# A question about reactive power

Tags: power, generator, reactive-power

I have two questions about reactive power.
1) I have read that the flow of reactive power is proportional to the magnitude of voltage difference between nodes. Could someone explain me this?
2) At the merchant vessel that i am working, if i increase the field excitation ( the current of generator's rotor ) the power factor increases. Why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by nodes?  Terminals?

Comment: the same meaning that nodes have in circuits, not terminals. I have read that in physics forum sitehttps://www.physicsforums.com/insights/ac-power-analysis-part-2-network-analysis/

Comment: The link does not go to anything appropriate.

Comment: go to physics forum and look for ac power analysis part 2 it is a very elegant analysis which i do not understand

Comment: Power, and reactive VA, are proportional to voltage squared.

Comment: The physics forum material is about the power grid network. It is not useful in the context of controlling an individual synchronous machine.

Comment: What is the meaning of the definition of flow?

Comment: On land you have an infinite bus, with many generators at different geographic locations.  At sea, you can have multiple generators, which can be paralleled, but that's to provide more power than one generator can supply.  Can be simplified to a really big generator.

Comment: Why when the current of the rotor is increased, the power factor increases as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magnetic field in a synchronous machine is caused by the net effect of the field current and the armature current. Increasing the field current of a generator can either increase or reduce the power factor of the generator depending on whether the starting point is a leading power factor or a lagging power factor as shown below.

[image]